# WebSocket permessage-deflate in Chrome with no context takeover

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, deflate

I have this problem with compression, and I am not sure if it is a bug. My WebSocket server does not support context takeover, and I am having problems sending messages, but not receiving.

The browser issues a request like this:

```
GET /socket HTTP/1.1
Host: thirdparty.com
Origin: http://example.com
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits, x-webkit-deflate-frame
```

If the server does not specify any option about context takeover:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
```

I can read and write the first message, but cannot do subsequent reads or writes, because Chrome expects the server is keeping the context.

So my server provides this answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_no_context_takeover; server_no_context_takeover
```

And now I can receive messages without problems, but again, I can only send the first message, the second message fails, and I see an error in Chrome saying that it failed at inflating the frame. I tried to send two identical strings, and I can see how the server is sending twice the same data, but the client fails to decompress it the second time.

So it seems that Chrome accepts the `client_no_context_takeover` parameter that specify that the client won't use the same compression context for all messages when compressing, but ignores `server_no_context_takeover` indicates the server won't use the same context.

Is this a bug in Chrome? I am not clear about if I can send options back that have not been offered/requested by the client.

Is there any other option I can use to disable the client context takeover?

**UPDATE:**

In **WebSocketPerMessageDeflate.cpp** in the [Chromium source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink.git/+/master/Source/modules/websockets/WebSocketPerMessageDeflate.cpp) code, I can see:

```
if (clientNoContextTakeover != parameters.end()) {
    if (!clientNoContextTakeover->value.isNull()) {
        m_failureReason = "Received invalid client_no_context_takeover parameter";
        return false;
    }
    mode = WebSocketDeflater::DoNotTakeOverContext;
    ++numProcessedParameters;
}
```

But also:

```
if (serverNoContextTakeover != parameters.end()) {
    if (!serverNoContextTakeover->value.isNull()) {
        m_failureReason = "Received invalid server_no_context_takeover parameter";
        return false;
    }
    ++numProcessedParameters;
}
```

In the first snippet, it is setting the "mode" variable, but in the second one is not doing nothing, so it seems it is basically ignoring the parameter.

Cheers.

Comment: how do you check if server returns gziped messages through websockets? I'm using sockjs and wondering if there is a way to check it somehow? Thank you in advance

Comment: In the websocket negotiation, the client will offer some capabilities like deflate compression and then the server may agree to use it : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7692

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-permessage-compression-17#section-8.2.3

> 8.2.3.4.  Using a DEFLATE Block with BFINAL Set to 1

Going through the examples in the draft I found my server was sending slightly different payloads. Turned out that the problem was the BFINAL, I need to set it to 0 by adding a 0 byte at the end.

Now it works.

Comment: Can you share the actual solution in more detail? Having the same issue, but I'm not familiar with a DEFLATE Block. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A server must send a `server_no_context_takeover` parameter in a response only if the client *requested* the "no context takeover". In essence, the server acknowledges the client's request.

If a server decides to do "no context takeover" for sending on it's own (without the client having requested it), that's fine. In this case, no parameter is sent by the server.

A deflate sender can always on it's own drop compression context and/or reduce compression window size. There is no need to tell the receiver. The deflate wire format has enough information for the receiver to cope with that.

[Here](https://github.com/crossbario/crossbar/wiki/WebSocket-Compression) is how configuration and handshake looks with [Crossbar.io](http://crossbar.io/).

Comment: Do you mean I should not send "server_no_context_takeover" ?

Comment: Yes. Do *not* send (since the client did not request it, but the server decided to drop context on your own).

Comment: I am afraid it does not work either. The client is trying to decompress the second message using the context used for the first one.

Comment: Well, Chrome + AutobahnPython do work with no context takeover being done by the server.

Comment: Your "here" link is dead, I think you wanted to point it here: https://github.com/crossbario/crossbar/blob/master/docs/WebSocket-Compression.rst